# How to Install Wine Library by GUID?

Tags: linux, opensuse, nvidia-geforce, wine, geforce-experience

I know you can uninstall stuff by typing `wine uninstaller --remove '{E45D8920-A758-4088-B6C6-31DBB276992E}'`, but what is the command to install a library by GUID ?

If I try to run Geforce Experience with Wine I get this:

```
fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
fixme:ole:CoInitializeSecurity ((nil),-1,(nil),(nil),0,3,(nil),0,(nil)) - stub!
fixme:ole:CoInitializeSecurity ((nil),-1,(nil),(nil),0,3,(nil),0,(nil)) - stub!
fixme:ole:CoInitializeSecurity ((nil),-1,(nil),(nil),0,3,(nil),0,(nil)) - stub!
fixme:gdiplus:resample_bitmap_pixel Unimplemented interpolation 7
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {d2e0fe7f-d23e-48e1-93c0-6fa8cc346474} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {d2e0fe7f-d23e-48e1-93c0-6fa8cc346474} not registered
err:ole:create_server class {d2e0fe7f-d23e-48e1-93c0-6fa8cc346474} not registered
fixme:ole:CoGetClassObject CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER not supported
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {d2e0fe7f-d23e-48e1-93c0-6fa8cc346474} could be created for context 0x17
```

As you can see, the library ***{d2e0fe7f-d23e-48e1-93c0-6fa8cc346474}*** is missing. How do I go about installing it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the command to install a library by GUID ?

There isn't one. You have to find and run an installer which includes the library.

> As you can see, the library `{d2e0fe7f-d23e-48e1-93c0-6fa8cc346474}` is missing. How do I go about installing it?

That GUID is associated with the IUpdateInstaller interface, which is part of the Windows Update subsystem. This is part of a standard Windows install; there is no standalone installer associated with it.

This application is unlikely to be usable under WINE.